# Python regex for matching all strings except a given string

Tags: python, regex

I want a regex which will match all strings of length greater than 0 (`.+`) but will not match the string: `"%"` i.e. a  string of length 1 containing `%`.

Comment: You don't need a regex for that, just `s != "%"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It'll be **much** cheaper to just test for the one-character `'%'` string:

```
if inputstring and inputstring != '%':
```

No regular expression required. The above expression tests if the string contains at least one character and is not exactly equal to `'%'`.

If you *must* use a regular expression, then match the negative character set for length one, `.` for length 2 and up:

```
r'^(?:[^%]|.{2,})$'
```

This matches 1 character if it is *not* `%`, or any characters if the string is length 2 or more.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> no_percentage = re.compile(r'^(?:[^%]|.{2,})$')
>>> no_percentage.search('')
>>> no_percentage.search('%')
>>> no_percentage.search('%1')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10f374370>
>>> no_percentage.search('1')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10f3743d8>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I don't want to match 0 characters. What should be the regex for that?

Comment: @Bruce: remove the `?`.

Answer (score 4):

This regex should work for you r'^([^%]|.{2,})$'
Explanation of the regex

- ^ - enforces that the expression is matched from the start
- ([^%] | .{2,}) - the [^%] part matches a single character which is not equal to '%'  and the                  part .{2,} means a string of length 2 or more made of any characters. The '|' sign enforces that the string is either of the two.
- $ - enforces that the expression is matched till the last element

but then again as mentioned an equality check should be much better and cleaner.